# percentage div overflow small

Tags: css, responsive-design, 960.gs

I'm creating a responsive website with the 960grid system and I have a little problem. If you take a look at the site http://www.mesquidatattoo.com/new in the div `#slide 4` or where the contact form is, when you resize the window to a mobile size horizontally, it overflows causing the inputs in it (that have a `width: 100%;`) to stretch and to be out of the container. I can do an `overflow: hidden;` but that does'nt solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
input[type=text],
textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This will take padding into account when calculating the element width.

You may need browser prefixes depending on which browsers you which to accomodate.

[box-sizing browser support](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing)